# R extrafont package, dependency ‘Rttf2pt1’ is not available

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install the package extrafont in R, but I get an error message about dependency "Rttf2pt1" is not available. I tried to find the package Rttf2pt1 in the CRAN repository, but no luck there. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: extrafont looks to be archived as well.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on your R version because apparently Rttf2pt1 is not built for the current version. But try

```
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rttf2pt1/Rttf2pt1_1.2.tar.gz")
```

or try it via the author's github using devtools

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("Rttf2pt1", "wch")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still not working. I get the following  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rttf2pt1'. I am using RStudio, might be a problem?

Comment: What you tell me what version of R you are working with?

Comment: R 3.0.2, RStudio 0.98.501

Comment: It compiles just fine in my computer, but I'm on Ubuntu. I assume your are on windows?

Comment: Yeah, I am. Ok, i'll try again on linux tomorrow. I have elementary, let's hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will work on linux, I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/wch/Rttf2pt1]) and you need a build enviorment to compile so you'll run into trouble if you don't have one in your windows install. You can always install visual studio or cygwin :p . Good luck!

Comment: Compiling with cygwin is not recommended. Try installing RTools package if planning to compile Windows pkgs from source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution that worked for me:

I installed the package manually. To do so

1. Download the package in a format compatible with your system on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rttf2pt1/index.html
2. Run `install.packages('C:/Users/eddy/Downloads/Rttf2pt1_1.3.5.zip', repos = NULL)` and replace it with the path where you stored the downloaded file.